# Magento - How to put Mageworx downloads block in Template master - Easy tabs, custom tab

Tags: magento, tabs

I have installed the Mageworx downloads extension and the Template master - Easy tabs extension. It is possible to configure via the admin, where the downloads information goes on the product view page, but it is not possible to tell it to place it in an 'Easy tabs' custom tab.

I have found where I need to make the edits, but I'm not sure of the right syntax:

downloads.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs" ifconfig="mageworx_cms/downloads/enabled"><script>mageworx/downloads.js</script></action>
            <action method="addCss" ifconfig="mageworx_cms/downloads/enabled"><stylesheet>css/mageworx/downloads.css</stylesheet></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="after_body_start">
            <block type="core/template" template="downloads/init_popup.phtml" name="init_video_popup" />
        </reference>
        <reference name="before_body_end">
            <block type="core/template" template="downloads/video_popup.phtml" name="video_popup" />
        </reference>
    </default>

    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="downloads/product" name="downloads.product" />
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>

    <!--catalog_category_layered>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <action ifconfig="mageworx_cms/downloads/enable_files_on_category_pages" method="setTemplate"><template>downloads/catalog-product-list.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_layered>

    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <action ifconfig="mageworx_cms/downloads/enable_files_on_category_pages" method="setTemplate"><template>downloads/catalog-product-list.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>

    <catalogsearch_result_index>
        <reference name="search_result_list">
            <action ifconfig="mageworx_cms/downloads/enable_files_on_category_pages" method="setTemplate"><template>downloads/catalog-product-list.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_result_index>

    <catalogsearch_advanced_result>
        <reference name="search_result_list">
            <action ifconfig="mageworx_cms/downloads/enable_files_on_category_pages" method="setTemplate"><template>downloads/catalog-product-list.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalogsearch_advanced_result-->
</layout>
```

TM_EasyTabs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <TM_EasyTabs>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>community</codePool>
            <tm_link><![CDATA[http://templates-master.com/magento-extensions/magento-easy-tabs.html]]></tm_link>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Catalog />
            </depends>
            <!-- Add custom tab for downloads -->
            <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog">
                <alias>downloads</alias>
                <title>Downloads test</title>
                <block>downloads/product</block>
                <template>downloads/block_file_links.phtml</template>
            </action>
         </TM_EasyTabs>   
    </modules>
</config>
```

As you can see I've made an attempt at putting the correct syntax in but I'm getting it wrong because the tabs disappear from the product page when I uncomment it.

EDIT:

Turns out I was editing the wrong xml file, the one I needed to edit was the easytabs.xml in the layout folder.

I've managed to add a tab with the downloads inside, but because I can't completely disable the addition of downloads in the admin, I now get two downloads tabs, one for my custom one and one that the downloads extension was supposed to add in, but didn't for some reason.

easytabs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/enabled"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/easytabs.css</name></action>
        </reference>
    </default>

    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/descriptiontabbed"><name>description</name></action>
            <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/additionaltabbed"><name>additional</name></action>
            <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/upsellproductstabbed"><name>upsell_products</name></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/relatedtabbed"><name>catalog.product.related</name></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.info.additional">
            <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/tagstabbed"><name>product_tag_list</name></action>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs">
                <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/enabled"><template>easytabs/tabs.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/descriptiontabbed"><alias>description_tabbed</alias><title>Description</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>easytabs/description.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/additionaltabbed"><alias>additional_tabbed</alias><title>Specification</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>easytabs/attributes.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/upsellproductstabbed"><alias>upsell_products_tabbed</alias><title>We Also Recommend</title><block>catalog/product_list_upsell</block><template>catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/relatedtabbed"><alias>related_tabbed</alias><title>Related Products</title><block>catalog/product_list_related</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductrelated.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="tag"     ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/tagstabbed"><alias>tags_tabbed</alias><title>Product Tags</title><block>tag/product_list</block><template>easytabs/catalogproducttags.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="review"  ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/reviewtabbed"><alias>review_tabbed</alias><title>Reviews</title><block>review/product_view_list</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductreview.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/custom/customtab"><alias>custom</alias><title>Custom tab</title><block>catalog/product_view</block><template>downloads/block_file_links.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/custom/customtab1"><alias>custom1</alias><title>Custom tab</title><block>catalog/product_view</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductcustom1.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/custom/customtab2"><alias>custom2</alias><title>Custom tab</title><block>catalog/product_view</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductcustom2.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/custom/customtab3"><alias>custom3</alias><title>Custom tab</title><block>catalog/product_view</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductcustom3.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/custom/customtab4"><alias>custom4</alias><title>Custom tab</title><block>catalog/product_view</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductcustom4.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/customcms/tabcms"><alias>cms</alias><title>CMS tab</title><block>core/template</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductcms.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/customcms/tabcms1"><alias>cms1</alias><title>CMS tab</title><block>core/template</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductcms1.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/customcms/tabcms2"><alias>cms2</alias><title>CMS tab</title><block>core/template</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductcms2.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/customcms/tabcms3"><alias>cms3</alias><title>CMS tab</title><block>core/template</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductcms3.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/customcms/tabcms4"><alias>cms4</alias><title>CMS tab</title><block>core/template</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductcms4.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="downloads">
                    <alias>downloads_test</alias>
                    <title>Downloads test</title>
                    <block>downloads/product</block>
                    <template>downloads/block_file_links.phtml</template>
                </action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

I now need to remove the extra tab, but removing my reference, removes both of them...

SOLVED:

Added this after my addTab action and it removed the extra tab:

```
<action method="unsetChild"><name>downloads_test</name></action>
```

Answer (score 0):

layout/easytabs.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/enabled"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/easytabs.css</name></action>
        </reference>
    </default>

    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/descriptiontabbed"><name>description</name></action>
            <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/additionaltabbed"><name>additional</name></action>
            <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/upsellproductstabbed"><name>upsell_products</name></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="right">
            <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/relatedtabbed"><name>catalog.product.related</name></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="product.info.additional">
            <action method="unsetChild" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/tagstabbed"><name>product_tag_list</name></action>
            <block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs">
                <action method="setTemplate" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/enabled"><template>easytabs/tabs.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/descriptiontabbed"><alias>description_tabbed</alias><title>Description</title><block>catalog/product_view_description</block><template>easytabs/description.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/additionaltabbed"><alias>additional_tabbed</alias><title>Specification</title><block>catalog/product_view_attributes</block><template>easytabs/attributes.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/upsellproductstabbed"><alias>upsell_products_tabbed</alias><title>We Also Recommend</title><block>catalog/product_list_upsell</block><template>catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/relatedtabbed"><alias>related_tabbed</alias><title>Related Products</title><block>catalog/product_list_related</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductrelated.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="tag"     ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/tagstabbed"><alias>tags_tabbed</alias><title>Product Tags</title><block>tag/product_list</block><template>easytabs/catalogproducttags.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="review"  ifconfig="easy_tabs/general/reviewtabbed"><alias>review_tabbed</alias><title>Reviews</title><block>review/product_view_list</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductreview.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/custom/customtab"><alias>custom</alias><title>Custom tab</title><block>catalog/product_view</block><template>downloads/block_file_links.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/custom/customtab1"><alias>custom1</alias><title>Custom tab</title><block>catalog/product_view</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductcustom1.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/custom/customtab2"><alias>custom2</alias><title>Custom tab</title><block>catalog/product_view</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductcustom2.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/custom/customtab3"><alias>custom3</alias><title>Custom tab</title><block>catalog/product_view</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductcustom3.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/custom/customtab4"><alias>custom4</alias><title>Custom tab</title><block>catalog/product_view</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductcustom4.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/customcms/tabcms"><alias>cms</alias><title>CMS tab</title><block>core/template</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductcms.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/customcms/tabcms1"><alias>cms1</alias><title>CMS tab</title><block>core/template</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductcms1.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/customcms/tabcms2"><alias>cms2</alias><title>CMS tab</title><block>core/template</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductcms2.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/customcms/tabcms3"><alias>cms3</alias><title>CMS tab</title><block>core/template</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductcms3.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="catalog" ifconfig="easy_tabs/customcms/tabcms4"><alias>cms4</alias><title>CMS tab</title><block>core/template</block><template>easytabs/catalogproductcms4.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addTab" translate="title" module="downloads">
                    <alias>downloads_test</alias>
                    <title>Downloads test</title>
                    <block>downloads/product</block>
                    <template>downloads/block_file_links.phtml</template>
                </action>
                <action method="unsetChild"><name>downloads_test</name></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

Answer (score 0):

File Downloads extension by MageWorx should be fully compatible with TM_EasyTabs.
The most likley reason of the problem is that FileDownloads extension is loaded before EasyTabs. To solve it, try to edit file app/etc/modules/MageWorx_Downloads.xml

```
From:
<config>
    <modules>
        <MageWorx_Downloads>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <extension_name><![CDATA[File Downloads & Product Attachments]]></extension_name>
        </MageWorx_Downloads>
    </modules>
</config>

To:
<config>
    <modules>
        <MageWorx_Downloads>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <extension_name><![CDATA[File Downloads & Product Attachments]]></extension_name>
            <depends><TM_EasyTabs /></depends>
        </MageWorx_Downloads>
    </modules>
</config>
```

If this does not help, feel free to contact MageWorx's support team.